# Problem getting a delete button on an UpdateView to redirect

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Python and Django newbie here

I've been trying to get a delete button onto a standard `UpdateView` form from Django and then get that to redirect to the `DeleteView` if that button is pressed instead of the submit button. I have that working but im not sure how to redirect to the corresponding delete page on click.

I expect i need to change the `reverse_lazy('app:submission_delete')` to include the id somehow but im a bit lost here, and my google fu isnt helping much either.

### views.py

```
class AssessmentUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Submission
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('app:index')

    def form_valid(self, request):
        if 'Delete' in self.request.POST:
            reverse_lazy('app:Submission_delete')
        else:
            self.object = request.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

### urls.py

```
app_name = 'app'
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:submission_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/update/', views.AssessmentUpdate.as_view(), name='Submission_update'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete/', views.AssessmentDelete.as_view(), name='Submission_delete'),
]
```

Comment: Do you really need a redirect here? Why not just use a href with the appropriate URL to the delete view? In the template use `{% url 'app:Submission_delete' pk=object.pk %}`

Comment: @Risadinha thanks for this. I did find some references to using this but got it into my head that i should rather use another button rather (not sure why). I tried to do it as i asked but the effort was huge to get it going (i never quite got it working). If you submit as answer ill just comment on that and mark it. Thanks

Comment: I've update my existing answer to include the hyper link solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a URL needs args or kwargs:

```
reverse_lazy('app:Submission_delete', kwargs={'pk': object.pk})
```

where `object` is the object which would be deleted.

ALTERNATIVELY:

Just use a regular hyper link to the delete page. Use django's template tag `url` for that:

```
{% url 'app:Submission_delete' pk=object.pk %}
```

You can still style that link like a button via CSS, so user's wouldn't even know the difference.